# STAMDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES’ undeclared while compling php extension

Tags: php-extension

When I compling my own php extension, I get this while make
**‘STAMDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES’ undeclared here (not in a function)**

```
zend_module_entry example_module_entry = {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "example",                                                                                                                       
    example_functions,                                                                                                               
    PHP_MINIT(example),                                                                                                              
    PHP_MSHUTDOWN(example),                                                                                                              
    PHP_RINIT(example),                                                 
    PHP_RSHUTDOWN(example),                                              
    PHP_MINFO(example),      
    "0.1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    STAMDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES,                                                                                                          
    PHP_GINIT(example),                                                                                                              
};
```

Comment: "STAMDARD"....?

Comment: I get wrong words

Comment: What is your version of PHP? Along with that, what is the value of ZEND_MODULE_API_NO?

Answer (score -1):

STAMDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES => STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES,

Comment: Are you providing the answer? Or correcting your question?